# Representing $\arcsin$ using a dot product

Tags: trigonometry, vectors

Suppose there are two vectors $\vec{x}, \vec{y} \in \mathbb{R}^n$. The angle $\theta$ between the two vectors can be represented as
$$
\theta = \arccos{\frac{\vec{x} \cdot \vec{y}}{||\vec{x}||\cdot||\vec{y}||}}
$$

Now, I am curious if there is a way to represent $\theta$ using $\arcsin$ and the dot product between the two vectors. In particular, the reason I began thinking about this is because
$$
\arcsin{\frac{\vec{x} \cdot \vec{y}}{||\vec{x}||\cdot||\vec{y}||}}
$$
will always fall within $[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}]$.

Comment: $\arcsin t+\arccos t=\pi/2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\cos\theta = {\frac{\vec{x} \cdot \vec{y}}{||\vec{x}||\cdot||\vec{y}||}}$$

but $\cos(\theta)=\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2} -\theta\right)$ and then

$$\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2} -\theta\right) = {\frac{\vec{x} \cdot \vec{y}}{||\vec{x}||\cdot||\vec{y}||}} \Rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2} -\theta=\arcsin\left(\frac{\vec{x} \cdot \vec{y}}{||\vec{x}||\cdot||\vec{y}||}\right)$$

$$\theta=\frac{\pi}{2} -\arcsin\left(\frac{\vec{x} \cdot \vec{y}}{||\vec{x}||\cdot||\vec{y}||}\right)$$